# Big project like hadoop

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, twitter-bootstrap

We’re working like hadoop big project. We’ve a problem.
We want to work on Java based CMS (Content management system). But this CMS must include Spring, hibernate, MySQL and must have Responsive interface (our library is twitter bootsrapt). 
Our project usually quite big so, what can i do ?

Comment: Hi, This question is really hard to answer. If you would try to specify your question, describe your problem in detail, and be concrete, it would be a lot easier to provide support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's your usage to hadoop? Is it just map and reduce? If so, I seriously recommend to write map-reduce part yourself. It's simple to code up as long as you have already object serialization and communication layer; and since you mention your project is big you probably have them already. Then the value of hadoop is just an interface and I am sure you can write it in more compact and adaptive way to suit your usage.

To me this is a typical case where a 3rd party lib gives you 20% of functionality you need while introducing 80% of its own rubbish. So I'd say just write your own.

BTW, if your use case is simple, you might also want to take a look at ForkJoinPool